# hide id or query string while passing through react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

i am having route where i pass id,but i dont want to show id in url,

```
`<Route path={`${match.url}invite-members/:groupID`} exact component={InviteMembers} />`
```

this gets converted in url https://local..../invite-members/5,
but instead of that i want https://local..../invite-members, but the functionality should remain the same as in i get id in invite-members through `this.props.match.params.groupID` should be as it is,please help

using react router `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",`

Comment: this is what requirement is,and they are secret id's that cant be revealed

Comment: Maybe you should generate a temporary token, depends on what you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change url to '/invite-members', you can add the Redirect component. And in case you want to save groupId, you could save it to your component state:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

class Root extends PureComponent {
  // add groupId field to your component
  // In case you use redux or any another state management library, you can save groupId to store
  state = { groupId: null };
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    // just for example I defined '/' path to redirect on /invite-members url
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/"
              exact
              render={props => (
                <Redirect
                  to={{
                    pathname: "/invite-members/123",
                    state: { from: props.location }
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/invite-members"
              exact
              render={props => (
                <InviteMembers {...props} groupId={this.state.groupId} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/invite-members/:groupID"
              exact
              render={props => {
                return (
                  <RedirectAndSaveGroupId
                    {...props}
                    groupId={props.match.params.groupID}
                    onSetGroupId={groupId => {
                      this.setState({ groupId });
                    }}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;

class RedirectAndSaveGroupId extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    // save groupId to Root component
    this.props.onSetGroupId(this.props.groupId);
  }

  render() {
    // redirect to /invite-members without groupId
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/invite-members",
          state: { from: this.props.location }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

// Just for demo. In this.props.groupId we can receive groupId
class InviteMembers extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return this.props.groupId;
  }
}
```

Note, that in case you using any state management library such as Redux, you can store group id in them

Answer (score 1):

I maybe have a very simple solution :

Router link :

```
 <Link to={{pathname: '/item/'+name, state : {id}}}>{name}</Link>
```

In the Targeted file :

```
 state = this.props.location.state

 QueryParameters = () => {
     const id = this.state.id
     return { id }
  }
```

And launch your query requiring the ID. It does not appear in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Passing data in the `params` object will *always* result in that data being shown in the URL. Because the `params` object is built from the url.

Comment: so can there be any alternative to it

Comment: You can try making groupID optional by changing the path to `invite-members/:groupID?` I'm not sure of your server setup to know if you could POST the groupID or not

Comment: I think Gabriel's suggestion of turning the ID into a token is probably your best bet. You can use the jwt libraries for this